# css shorth version of element:hover + element + element

Tags: css

Have worked example:

```css
.hov:hover+.next+.result {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hov">hover</div>
<div class="next">next</div>
<div class="result">result</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y04p35bn/)

When hover on first element the third element have result. Any shorthen version of `+ +` if i need more `+ +`, something like `.hov:hover+div:nth-child(2)` - but this not work.

Comment: @Randy need an event of element:hover + :nth-next(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make what you want to do shorter. This is simply the way the selector works. The solution you proposed (`element + next(3)` or whatever syntax you whish to use there) does not exist.

Your selector has some issues if you change the structure of your HTML (for example add a paragraph in between). What you can do to make your code more reliable is answered by Nisarg and use the `~` selector to select elements.

Why not change the HTML and make it more reliable? What you are doing here is working for you maybe, but if you make changes to your HTML this CSS breaks. Try adding classes for all items you want selected. Don't worry if you have three or four classes on elements, that is completely normal.

```css
.hov:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hov">hover</div>
<div class="next hov">next</div>
<div class="result hov">result</div>
```

Comment: ``The solution you proposed (element + next(3) or whatever syntax you whish to use there) does not exist.``

Answer (score 1):

`+` is [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) in CSS, so it requires both selector elements to be next to each other. Instead, you can use `~` which is [General Sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) here, which doesn't require the two elements to be next to each other.

```css
.hov:hover ~ .result {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hov">hover</div>
<div class="next">next</div>
<div class="result">result</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution because it is way more reliable and robust, but still, it does not feel like this is a better solution than adding extra classes to the HTML elements.